# Test OBD iOS App without using vehicle

Tags: ios, obd-ii

Currently, I am working on an iOS App using OBD device. How can I test it without  using a vehicle.

Comment: You will need to create a class that provides simulates the device and provides mock data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to purchase a simulator, which can be upwards of $300-400, or you could setup a bench ECU.

You should be able to find an ECU in a junkyard for $20-40 with the connector then you just need to wire it to an OBD2 port and a 12V for power.  No messing around with creating testing classes, you'll be dealing with real world implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can either, as one commenter suggested, write a class that implements a common device interface and provides mock data, or use a hardware simulator like [this one](https://www.scantool.net/ecusim-2000/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with iOS is that BT OBD adapters will not work, only BT-LE.

I took the following approach:

- OBDSim has a [TCP fork](https://github.com/oesmith/obdgpslogger) that lets it run using a TCP channel (note that this is different from -g Socket - this does not create a TCP channel for communication)
- I compiled this fork and it works great. I run it on OS X using `obdsim -T 5000 -g Cycle` which runs it onTCP port  5000
- Next up,there is a fork of  `node-blueooth-obd` package which added an option to make it work over TCP as well. You can find the fork [here](https://github.com/hsccorp/node-bluetooth-tcp-obd)
- Finally, you can use ionic & cordova to use this forked library and communicate with a TCP based OBD simulator - see an example [here](https://github.com/hsccorp/obd-tcp-test)

This setup is great for testing, and you should be able to swap OBDsim with WiFi ODB adaptors like [OBDlink](http://www.obdlink.com/mxwf/) from Scantool